# docusign splits up the html content between two pages while converting html to pdf

Tags: docusignapi

while sending html document to DocuSign, Some of the content is displayed in middle of two pages

[Example Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WtZnw.png)

I want it to be on next page, not being splitted at the page break.

How can I do that?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! PLEASE check (accept) the best answer to each of your questions. THANK YOU!

Comment: yeah for sure!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

DocuSign HTML supports page breaks within the HTML body.

To create a page break, include the following in your HTML:

```
<div style="page-break-before:always">&nbsp;</div>
```

The trick is that the block element (the `<div>`) that you want to be on a new page must, itself, contain character content.

```
<!-- the following has no content and will NOT cause a page break -->
<div style="page-break-before:always"></div>
```

Comment: Hi Larry - I'm attempting to use this answer and get the following error.

Disallowed: CSS properties [page-break-before]

Comment: Hi @ChrisRidenour -- Please submit as a new stack overflow question with tag `docusignapi` . Include api log. Thanks.